# Valgrind gives "Invalid write of size 8" over an empty destructor

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have a declared a:

```
std::map<unsigned int, MyClass> *myMap;
```

into a certain class A. This map is created in A's constructor:

```
myMap = new std::map<unsigned int, MyClass>;
```

The class MyClass is basically an struct to store some data with some getters/setters. There are not any pointers or new instances into MyClass, just a pair of enum values, an unsigned int and a bool. So MyClass destructor is empty.

On the other hand, into A's destructor i'm deleting the map:

```
A::~A(){
    if(myMap!=NULL){
        delete myMap;
        myMap = NULL;
    }
}
```

Here Valgrind is telling me *"Address 0x4c389b0 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 48 free'd[PID:6077]"* over the delete line.

Also, at MyClass destructor, even being empty, I'm getting *"Invalid write of size 8[PID:6077]"*

I don't understand were the problem is. I always thought that calling a delete over a vector or map would automatically call each element correspondent destructor, and in this case that destructor has nothing to do.

Any help?

EDIT: Added A's constructor:

```
A::A(unsigned int someValue){
    m_someValue = someValue;
    initializeMap();
}

void A::initializeMap(){
myMap = new std::map<unsigned int, MyClass>;
    for(unsigned int i=1; i<=20; i++)
        mymap->insert(std::make_pair(i,
                MyClass(i)));
}
```

Also, MyClass constructor:

```
SvAvailabitlity::SvAvailabitlity(unsigned int index){
    m_index = index; //unsigned int
    m_Flag = false; //bool
        m_enumData1 = NOT_OK; //enum MyEnum
    m_enumData2 = NOT_OK; //enum MyEnum
}
```

Where MyEnum is defined as:

```
typedef enum {
    OK = 0,
    NOT_OK = 1,
} MyEnum;
```

BTW, I don't understand the negative vote. Someone could also please explain that, just in case  am offending someone with this question which I think it is right according to stackoverflow rules.

Comment: Please post code for `A` (constructors, assignment operator).

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior with a simple main() where you only allocate and delete a map?

Comment: Could you please check, that it's not a MyClass problem? Destructor of MyClass is empty, but does so the destructors of MyClass members? To test try to cleanup myMap before and then delete it. P.S. is there any need to have std::map heap allocated?

Comment: This is most likely a [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) violation. (Can you paste the code that winds up calling the destructor? And can you paste A's copy assignment and copy constructors?)

Comment: I have edited including constructors. There are no assignment operators declared, nor copy constructors. As I said, MyClass members are the default types of data of the language.

Comment: Object could be copied behind the scenes. If you are using C++11, explicitly delete copy constructor, otherwise put it into private methods.

Comment: @hate-engine please explain that better: how could that happen?

Comment: @RomanRdgz, via function return or placing objects of `A` in some container.

Comment: @RomanRdgz: Then any copy of an instance of your class will cause this problem, since both instances will have the same pointer, they'll both delete it. You can easily wind up copying without realizing you're doing it. (For example, passing by value or putting into a vector.)

Comment: Ok, The problem was passing by value AND putting into a map. Now I pass a pointer to the map, and release it before delating the map. I can accept that as an answer @DavidSchwartz

Comment: possible duplicate of [Am I violating Rule of three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139103/am-i-violating-rule-of-three)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a rule of three violation. Any copy of your object will cause a double-free.